# HTML rows displaying side-by-side rather than vertically within column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2

Should this div not display my two rows one on top of the other? or am I missing something?

**the rows called 'tabs' and 'main' are displaying side-to-tide within the column('main' on the left), rather than tabs on top main below**

**Content div:**

```
<div class='row content'>
        <div class='col-12' style='display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content: center;'>
            <div class='row tabs' style='align-items: flex-start; width:100%; '> 
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style='display:flex; flex-direction:row; position:absolute; right:0;'>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Posts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Replies</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Media</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">More</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='row main' style='min-height:100px; width:100%;'>{{user.username}} 's profile </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content{
    width: 103.5%;
    min-height:50%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    background-color: #F3D5AE;
}

.tabs{
    position: relative;
    top:0%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a mock up of what you want to achieve, the question is a bit confusing...

Comment: @caiovisk okay I edited the question, hopefully more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly you really just want something like shown below. I'd suggest getting more familiar with the different [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) bootstrap provides to avoid repetitive (and in many cases unnecessary) styles since your usage of `flex` and `position` etc isn't correct and could make your output cleaner in the process. Cheers

```css
.example {
  background-color: #F3D5AE;
}

.example2 {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='row example'>
    <div class='col-12'>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Posts</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Replies</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Media</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">More</a>
          </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="col-12 example2">
        {{user.username}}'s profile
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```